# Modify specifics lines on a text file in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a test.txt  file which contains

```
bla bla bla
ble ble
BEGIN_SCAN
100 150
200 300
150 800
END_SCAN
blebleble
blublublu
```

I would like to change only the numbers between `BEGIN_SCAN` and `END_SCAN` for this matrix

```
M = [100 125;
     200 350;
     150 835]
```

saving the result on `result.txt` file.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
txt = fileread('test.txt');
rows = regexp(txt,'\n','split');
[Lia, irows_begin] = ismember('BEGIN_SCAN', rows);
[Lia, irows_end] = ismember('END_SCAN', rows);
M_before = rows(irows_begin+1:irows_end-1);
M_before = cellfun(@(x) cell2mat(cellfun(@(y) str2num(y), strsplit(x, ' '), 'un', 0)), M_before, 'un', 0);
M_before = cell2mat(M_before(:));
M = [M_before(:,1) [125;350;835]];
M = num2cell(M, 2);
M = cellfun(@num2str, M, 'un', 0)';
rows = [rows(1:irows_begin) M rows(irows_end:end)];
fid = fopen('result.txt','wt');
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', rows{:});
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [fseek](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/fseek.html) to move to a specific position (you'll first have to find it of course) in the file, and then use [fprintf](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) to overwrite what's on that line.

This is for example used in [export_fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig/content/export_fig.m) in the function `eps_remove_background` to remove a line from a file.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from @Will's answer to work properly:

```
fid=fopen('test.txt');
txt =textscan(fid,'%s','delimiter','\n');
rows = txt{1,1};
irows_begin = find(ismember(rows,'BEGIN_SCAN'));
irows_end = find(ismember(rows,'END_SCAN'));
fclose(fid)

M_before = rows(irows_begin+1:irows_end-1);
M_before=cellfun(@str2num,M_before,'UniformOutput',false);
M_before = cell2mat(M_before(:));
M = [M_before(:,1) [125;350;835]];
M = num2cell(M, 2);
M = cellfun(@num2str, M, 'un', 0);
rows = [rows(1:irows_begin); M; rows(irows_end:end)];

fid = fopen('result.txt','wt');
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', rows{:});
fclose(fid);
```